# Windows XP exposing websites in IIS in local network

Tags: iis, web, windows-xp

how can I expose my Website to other PC's in my local network? Say I my computer name is `CompTest` and I can access my websites deployed in IIS in my own machine in `http://Comptest/` and `http://localhost/`.  Is there anything I need to set so other computers in my local network can access `http://CompTest/`?  Just within local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable HTTP (port 80) over TCP through the Windows Firewall (in the Control Panel).

Answer (score 0):

try using your ip address rather the your host name. like **http://[ip address]:[port no]/[site name]**. for your info *http port is 80*. also do

- disable firewall
- use static ip

i hope this will help you

Comment: i don't want to disable my firewall, that will lessen my security since I'm just using XP. and I don't have access to the DHCP server :)

Comment: try it with enabled firewall security